# Why is my string to string comparison In Java using the string.equals() method yeilding different results on 2 different queries with similar syntax?

Tags: java, string, csv

I'm wondering why my string to string comparison In Java using the string.equals() method yeilding different results on 2 different queries with similar syntax?

Here are the details:

I'm doing a string to string comparison in java. The data is being pulled from a CSV using the util scanner. It's then populated onto a string array called data[]. Then I'm pulling the data from the string array. After that I am trying to match a user input to the scanned values contained within the data[] array. I'm using a while loop with if statements to accomplish this. Specifically, I am using the string.equals()) method to do this.

Now this has led me to an odd situation.

I use the string.equals() method twice. Both are written in the same way using the same syntax with the only difference being the text searched for and possibly the way the text is written in the CSV.

When I use the

```
 if(brand1.equals(data[counter2]))
        {
            System.out.print("Brand == " + data[counter2] + " ");
        }
```

It prints out nothing.

When I use the

```
    if(modelnumber1.equals(data[counter2]))
    {
        System.out.print("Model == " + data[counter2] + " ");
    }
```

It prints out model == *model number*.

I've tripple checked the spelling of the answer typed into brand1. I've copied and pasted my brand1 data into notepad too to ensure there were no hidden characters. That also failed. I next tried checking syntax, but kept coming back blank.

Is this a Syntax issue is this likely a CSV issue or is this something else entirely?

Here is the program in question so far:

```
package valveconversion;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValveConversion {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int counter1 = 0;  
        int counter2 = 0;
        String brand2 = "";
        String model2 = "";
        String notes ="";
        String data[] = new String[9999];
        String brand1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the brand?");
        String modelnumber1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the model number?");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\CNC DEPARTMENT\\Desktop\\ConversionTable.csv"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            data[counter1] = (scanner.next());
            counter1 = counter1 + 1;
        }
        scanner.close(); 
        while(counter2 < counter1)
        {           
        if(brand1.equals(data[counter2]))
        {
            System.out.print("Brand == " + data[counter2] + " ");
        }

        if(modelnumber1.equals(data[counter2]))
        {
            System.out.print("Model == " + data[counter2] + " ");
        } 
        counter2 = counter2 + 1;
        }        
   }    
}
```

Comment: The first can only print nothing if the text is getting stuck in the buffer, which is possible since you're using `print`, not `println`, and the buffer auto flushes when it's full, or it reaches a newline. Add `System.out.flush()` after the call and see if it prints.

Comment: I added  System.out.flush();  in the following context and the results were the same.                                                                                                                                                                        if(brand1.equals(data[counter2]))
        {
            System.out.println("Brand == " + data[counter2] + " ");
            System.out.flush();
        }

Comment: Then that means `brand1.equals(data[counter2])` is false. Check the data again.

Comment: I added println to both and System.out.flush(); to both. This was the output: Model == 072372AHP5

Comment: When all else fails, step through the code with a debugger and look at every instance of that comparison.  Or add an else block and print every instance of the comparison failing.  From there, you can at least see if the data that's flowing through the system while it's running matches your expectations.

Comment: "Then that means brand1.equals(data[counter2]) is false. Check the data again. " 
          Well, I am searching for Moog, which appears 3 times on the csv. When I type it into the system and scan for it, it detects none through my javaprogram. The whole system.outprintln is to check to make sure it's receiving data anyway. The longterm goal is to use this process as a way for a user to see what we have in stock.

Comment: I would start by adding a `if (brand1.equals(modelnumber1))` upfront for example. And print the two values, ideally with some marker chars around, so that you notice trailing spaces and such things.

Comment: Update: So, colunm 1 and column 3 in my spreadsheet both have brand names. When I put an input that was in column3 in as the input for "brand1", it can sucessfully retrieve data from column 3.  For some reason it doesn't seem to be able to retrieve data from column 1 of the csv.

Comment: Update2: So, I added a column to the left of column 1 in the csv called blank. Each value in the column has the value, "Blank". Now my java program can successfully search for brand1 and spits out results.

Answer (score 0):

I could see scanner is not reading the csv file properly.
Inspect your data array being created, when i checked your program with following data in CSV file

```
Honda, crv
Toyota, Camry
```

Data Array was built as follows

```
[Honda, crv\r\nToyota, Camry]
```

so i fixed scanner as follows

```
 while(scanner.hasNext())
        {
            data[counter1] = (scanner.next().replace(",", ""));
            counter1 = counter1 + 1;
        }
```

This time array got created as `[Honda, crv, Toyotda, Camry]` and able to get proper out put also